# Do there (or did there historically) exist Tamil Brahmin communities that are strictly Shaivite (i.e., neither Smarta nor (Sri) Vaishnavite)?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, brahmins, shaivism, smarta, tamil

Do/did *strictly* Shaivite Tamil Brahmin subcastes exist, and if so what is their origin. In the case of such a a Shaivite community that no longer exists, to which groups were they later assimilated to with respect to identity/philosophy and why did they disappear?

Comment: [Dikshitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dikshitar) and [Gurukkal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurukkal)